# Rails app doesn't load updates to Javascript files until I run rails assets:precompile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have an old Rails app that I'm trying to upgrade to Rails 7. Somewhere in the upgrade process I broke the asset pipeline. When I make updates to a javascript file, the changes aren't visible unless I run `rails assets:precompile` and restart the server.

When I do run `rails assets:precompile`, I get a bunch of compiled JS and CSS assets in my public/assets folder. This seems like an outdated version of the asset pipeline process.

This project is a personal project that I've had lying around for years and it spans Rails versions from 4 to 7. It's never had a user base, it's just an idea that I go back and work on from time to time. So it's possible I have an old version of the assets pipeline running.

I created a new Rails 7 project from scratch and it works as expected. I've been trying to make the new project as close to my existing project as I can to see where my current project is breaking, but that is becoming extremely difficult and not yielding any results yet.

I'm sure I must have some old configuration still in place but I have no idea where to look. I can't remember ever having this problem before. I would love any suggestions on where to look for differences between the old broken application and the new one that works.

Comment: Rails 7 leans on new tools like `bin/dev` now, so it's worth checking out the documentation on the new asset pipeline.

Comment: Hi @tadman thanks for the suggestion - neither my old project or my new project has `bin/dev`, but there are some diffs between the bin/ folders for the respective projects. I will look into those.

Comment: It can be a pretty jarring change, so have a look at what options Rails 7 offers for the new [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), especially by using `rails new` to try out various combinations on a test project.

Answer (score -1):

So this is really unsatisfying, but what finally resolved this issue was that I removed the `bootsnap` gem. I don't know what was happening or why, but after removing this gem, it behaved normally.